# Azure AKS - Cert-Manager - Certificate not created

Tags: azure-aks, cert-manager

After upgrade of Cert manager to 1.12.0 certificates aren't renewed.

Environment details:

- Kubernetes version: 1.24.9
- Cloud-provider/provisioner : Azure (AKS)
- cert-manager version: 1.12.0

Here is the log from the cert manager pod

`I0604 15:49:31.994623       1 start.go:75] "cert-manager: starting controller" version="v1.12.0" git-commit="bd192c4f76dd883f9ee908035b894ffb49002384" I0604 15:49:31.994773       1 controller.go:250] "cert-manager/controller/build-context: configured acme dns01 nameservers" nameservers=[10.0.0.10:53] W0604 15:49:31.995735       1 client_config.go:618] Neither --kubeconfig nor --master was specified.  Using the inClusterConfig.  This might not work. I0604 15:49:32.005770       1 controller.go:71] "cert-manager/controller: enabled controllers: [certificaterequests-approver certificaterequests-issuer-acme certificaterequests-issuer-ca certificaterequests-issuer-selfsigned certificaterequests-issuer-vault certificaterequests-issuer-venafi certificates-issuing certificates-key-manager certificates-metrics certificates-readiness certificates-request-manager certificates-revision-manager certificates-trigger challenges clusterissuers ingress-shim issuers orders]" I0604 15:49:32.006298       1 controller.go:92] "cert-manager/controller: starting metrics server" address="[::]:9402" I0604 15:49:32.006319       1 controller.go:144] "cert-manager/controller: starting leader election" I0604 15:49:32.006981       1 controller.go:137] "cert-manager/controller: starting healthz server" address="[::]:9403" I0604 15:49:32.007772       1 leaderelection.go:245] attempting to acquire leader lease kube-system/cert-manager-controller... I0604 15:50:44.841086       1 leaderelection.go:255] successfully acquired lease kube-system/cert-manager-controller I0604 15:50:44.845249       1 controller.go:214] "cert-manager/controller: starting controller" controller="challenges" I0604 15:50:44.846151       1 controller.go:214] "cert-manager/controller: starting controller" controller="orders" I0604 15:50:44.847305       1 controller.go:214] "cert-manager/controller: starting controller" controller="ingress-shim" I0604 15:50:44.848096       1 controller.go:214] "cert-manager/controller: starting controller" controller="certificaterequests-issuer-acme" I0604 15:50:44.848703       1 controller.go:214] "cert-manager/controller: starting controller" controller="certificaterequests-approver" I0604 15:50:44.849516       1 controller.go:214] "cert-manager/controller: starting controller" controller="certificaterequests-issuer-ca" I0604 15:50:44.849941       1 controller.go:214] "cert-manager/controller: starting controller" controller="certificaterequests-issuer-venafi" I0604 15:50:44.850536       1 controller.go:191] "cert-manager/controller: not starting controller as it's disabled" controller="certificatesigningrequests-issuer-ca" I0604 15:50:44.850614       1 controller.go:191] "cert-manager/controller: not starting controller as it's disabled" controller="certificatesigningrequests-issuer-venafi" I0604 15:50:44.851207       1 controller.go:191] "cert-manager/controller: not starting controller as it's disabled" controller="gateway-shim" I0604 15:50:44.851567       1 controller.go:214] "cert-manager/controller: starting controller" controller="clusterissuers" I0604 15:50:44.851217       1 controller.go:214] "cert-manager/controller: starting controller" controller="certificates-metrics" I0604 15:50:44.852306       1 controller.go:214] "cert-manager/controller: starting controller" controller="certificaterequests-issuer-vault" I0604 15:50:44.852858       1 controller.go:214] "cert-manager/controller: starting controller" controller="certificates-revision-manager" I0604 15:50:44.853016       1 controller.go:191] "cert-manager/controller: not starting controller as it's disabled" controller="certificatesigningrequests-issuer-selfsigned" I0604 15:50:44.853094       1 controller.go:191] "cert-manager/controller: not starting controller as it's disabled" controller="certificatesigningrequests-issuer-vault" I0604 15:50:44.853429       1 controller.go:214] "cert-manager/controller: starting controller" controller="certificates-trigger" I0604 15:50:44.853933       1 controller.go:214] "cert-manager/controller: starting controller" controller="issuers" I0604 15:50:44.854411       1 controller.go:214] "cert-manager/controller: starting controller" controller="certificaterequests-issuer-selfsigned" I0604 15:50:44.859175       1 controller.go:214] "cert-manager/controller: starting controller" controller="certificates-key-manager" I0604 15:50:44.859904       1 controller.go:214] "cert-manager/controller: starting controller" controller="certificates-issuing" I0604 15:50:44.860749       1 controller.go:214] "cert-manager/controller: starting controller" controller="certificates-readiness" I0604 15:50:44.861242       1 controller.go:191] "cert-manager/controller: not starting controller as it's disabled" controller="certificatesigningrequests-issuer-acme" I0604 15:50:44.861554       1 controller.go:214] "cert-manager/controller: starting controller" controller="certificates-request-manager" W0604 15:50:44.870284       1 reflector.go:533] k8s.io/client-go@v0.27.1/tools/cache/reflector.go:231: failed to list *v1.CertificateRequest: request to convert CR from an invalid group/version: cert-manager.io/v1alpha2 E0604 15:50:44.870319       1 reflector.go:148] k8s.io/client-go@v0.27.1/tools/cache/reflector.go:231: Failed to watch *v1.CertificateRequest: failed to list *v1.CertificateRequest: request to convert CR from an invalid group/version: cert-manager.io/v1alpha2 W0604 15:50:44.872546       1 reflector.go:533] k8s.io/client-go@v0.27.1/tools/cache/reflector.go:231: failed to list *v1.Order: request to convert CR from an invalid group/version: acme.cert-manager.io/v1alpha2 E0604 15:50:44.872831       1 reflector.go:148] k8s.io/client-go@v0.27.1/tools/cache/reflector.go:231: Failed to watch *v1.Order: failed to list *v1.Order: request to convert CR from an invalid group/version: acme.cert-manager.io/v1alpha2 W0604 15:50:45.685587       1 reflector.go:533] k8s.io/client-go@v0.27.1/tools/cache/reflector.go:231: failed to list *v1.Order: request to convert CR from an invalid group/version: acme.cert-manager.io/v1alpha2 E0604 15:50:45.685636       1 reflector.go:148] k8s.io/client-go@v0.27.1/tools/cache/reflector.go:231: Failed to watch *v1.Order: failed to list *v1.Order: request to convert CR from an invalid group/version: acme.cert-manager.io/v1alpha2 W0604 15:50:46.328237       1 reflector.go:533] k8s.io/client-go@v0.27.1/tools/cache/reflector.go:231: failed to list *v1.CertificateRequest: request to convert CR from an invalid group/version: cert-manager.io/v1alpha2 E0604 15:50:46.328285       1 reflector.go:148] k8s.io/client-go@v0.27.1/tools/cache/reflector.go:231: Failed to watch *v1.CertificateRequest: failed to list *v1.CertificateRequest: request to convert CR from an invalid group/version: cert-manager.io/v1alpha2 W0604 15:50:48.120702       1 reflector.go:533] k8s.io/client-go@v0.27.1/tools/cache/reflector.go:231: failed to list *v1.Order: request to convert CR from an invalid group/version: acme.cert-manager.io/v1alpha2 E0604 15:50:48.120747       1 reflector.go:148] k8s.io/client-go@v0.27.1/tools/cache/reflector.go:231: Failed to watch *v1.Order: failed to list *v1.Order: request to convert CR from an invalid group/version: acme.cert-manager.io/v1alpha2 W0604 15:50:49.140178       1 reflector.go:533] k8s.io/client-go@v0.27.1/tools/cache/reflector.go:231: failed to list *v1.CertificateRequest: request to convert CR from an invalid group/version: cert-manager.io/v1alpha2 E0604 15:50:49.140228       1 reflector.go:148] k8s.io/client-go@v0.27.1/tools/cache/reflector.go:231: Failed to watch *v1.CertificateRequest: failed to list *v1.CertificateRequest: request to convert CR from an invalid group/version: cert-manager.io/v1alpha2 W0604 15:50:53.702476       1 reflector.go:533] k8s.io/client-go@v0.27.1/tools/cache/reflector.go:231: failed to list *v1.Order: request to convert CR from an invalid group/version: acme.cert-manager.io/v1alpha2 E0604 15:50:53.702531       1 reflector.go:148] k8s.io/client-go@v0.27.1/tools/cache/reflector.go:231: Failed to watch *v1.Order: failed to list *v1.Order: request to convert CR from an invalid group/version: acme.cert-manager.io/v1alpha2 W0604 15:50:54.475974       1 reflector.go:533] k8s.io/client-go@v0.27.1/tools/cache/reflector.go:231: failed to list *v1.CertificateRequest: request to convert CR from an invalid group/version: cert-manager.io/v1alpha2 E0604 15:50:54.476022       1 reflector.go:148] k8s.io/client-go@v0.27.1/tools/cache/reflector.go:231: Failed to watch *v1.CertificateRequest: failed to list *v1.CertificateRequest: request to convert CR from an invalid group/version: cert-manager.io/v1alpha2 W0604 15:51:02.296722       1 reflector.go:533] k8s.io/client-go@v0.27.1/tools/cache/reflector.go:231: failed to list *v1.Order: request to convert CR from an invalid group/version: acme.cert-manager.io/v1alpha2 E0604 15:51:02.296773       1 reflector.go:148] k8s.io/client-go@v0.27.1/tools/cache/reflector.go:231: Failed to watch *v1.Order: failed to list *v1.Order: request to convert CR from an invalid group/version: acme.cert-manager.io/v1alpha2 W0604 15:51:04.365894       1 reflector.go:533] k8s.io/client-go@v0.27.1/tools/cache/reflector.go:231: failed to list *v1.CertificateRequest: request to convert CR from an invalid group/version: cert-manager.io/v1alpha2 E0604 15:51:04.365951       1 reflector.go:148] k8s.io/client-go@v0.27.1/tools/cache/reflector.go:231: Failed to watch *v1.CertificateRequest: failed to list *v1.CertificateRequest: request to convert CR from an invalid group/version: cert-manager.io/v1alpha2 W0604 15:51:23.604640       1 reflector.go:533] k8s.io/client-go@v0.27.1/tools/cache/reflector.go:231: failed to list *v1.CertificateRequest: request to convert CR from an invalid group/version: cert-manager.io/v1alpha2 E0604 15:51:23.604837       1 reflector.go:148] k8s.io/client-go@v0.27.1/tools/cache/reflector.go:231: Failed to watch *v1.CertificateRequest: failed to list *v1.CertificateRequest: request to convert CR from an invalid group/version: cert-manager.io/v1alpha2 W0604 15:51:26.442733       1 reflector.go:533] k8s.io/client-go@v0.27.1/tools/cache/reflector.go:231: failed to list *v1.Order: request to convert CR from an invalid group/version: acme.cert-manager.io/v1alpha2 E0604 15:51:26.442978       1 reflector.go:148] k8s.io/client-go@v0.27.1/tools/cache/reflector.go:231: Failed to watch *v1.Order: failed to list *v1.Order: request to convert CR from an invalid group/version: acme.cert-manager.io/v1alpha2 W0604 15:51:50.603131       1 reflector.go:533] k8s.io/client-go@v0.27.1/tools/cache/reflector.go:231: failed to list *v1.CertificateRequest: request to convert CR from an invalid group/version: cert-manager.io/v1alpha2 E0604 15:51:50.603176       1 reflector.go:148] k8s.io/client-go@v0.27.1/tools/cache/reflector.go:231: Failed to watch *v1.CertificateRequest: failed to list *v1.CertificateRequest: request to convert CR from an invalid group/version: cert-manager.io/v1alpha2 W0604 15:51:52.865282       1 reflector.go:533] k8s.io/client-go@v0.27.1/tools/cache/reflector.go:231: failed to list *v1.Order: request to convert CR from an invalid group/version: acme.cert-manager.io/v1alpha2 E0604 15:51:52.865325       1 reflector.go:148] k8s.io/client-go@v0.27.1/tools/cache/reflector.go:231: Failed to watch *v1.Order: failed to list *v1.Order: request to convert CR from an invalid group/version: acme.cert-manager.io/v1alpha2 W0604 15:52:29.536838       1 reflector.go:533] k8s.io/client-go@v0.27.1/tools/cache/reflector.go:231: failed to list *v1.CertificateRequest: request to convert CR from an invalid group/version: cert-manager.io/v1alpha2 E0604 15:52:29.536884       1 reflector.go:148] k8s.io/client-go@v0.27.1/tools/cache/reflector.go:231: Failed to watch *v1.CertificateRequest: failed to list *v1.CertificateRequest: request to convert CR from an invalid group/version: cert-manager.io/v1alpha2 W0604 15:52:48.829019       1 reflector.go:533] k8s.io/client-go@v0.27.1/tools/cache/reflector.go:231: failed to list *v1.Order: request to convert CR from an invalid group/version: acme.cert-manager.io/v1alpha2 E0604 15:52:48.829080       1 reflector.go:148] k8s.io/client-go@v0.27.1/tools/cache/reflector.go:231: Failed to watch *v1.Order: failed to list *v1.Order: request to convert CR from an invalid group/version: acme.cert-manager.io/v1alpha2 W0604 15:53:26.064694       1 reflector.go:533] k8s.io/client-go@v0.27.1/tools/cache/reflector.go:231: failed to list *v1.CertificateRequest: request to convert CR from an invalid group/version: cert-manager.io/v1alpha2 E0604 15:53:26.064740       1 reflector.go:148] k8s.io/client-go@v0.27.1/tools/cache/reflector.go:231: Failed to watch *v1.CertificateRequest: failed to list *v1.CertificateRequest: request to convert CR from an invalid group/version: cert-manager.io/v1alpha2 W0604 15:53:35.082675       1 reflector.go:533] k8s.io/client-go@v0.27.1/tools/cache/reflector.go:231: failed to list *v1.Order: request to convert CR from an invalid group/version: acme.cert-manager.io/v1alpha2 E0604 15:53:35.082722       1 reflector.go:148] k8s.io/client-go@v0.27.1/tools/cache/reflector.go:231: Failed to watch *v1.Order: failed to list *v1.Order: request to convert CR from an invalid group/version: acme.cert-manager.io/v1alpha2 E0604 15:53:43.509310       1 controller.go:167] "cert-manager/ingress-shim: re-queuing item due to error processing" err="certificates.cert-manager.io \"echo-tls-1\" not found" key="devtest/erpdeploymentdevtest-ingress" W0604 15:53:58.410338       1 reflector.go:533] k8s.io/client-go@v0.27.1/tools/cache/reflector.go:231: failed to list *v1.CertificateRequest: request to convert CR from an invalid group/version: cert-manager.io/v1alpha2 E0604 15:53:58.410459       1 reflector.go:148] k8s.io/client-go@v0.27.1/tools/cache/reflector.go:231: Failed to watch *v1.CertificateRequest: failed to list *v1.CertificateRequest: request to convert CR from an invalid group/version: cert-manager.io/v1alpha2 W0604 15:54:22.052195       1 reflector.go:533] k8s.io/client-go@v0.27.1/tools/cache/reflector.go:231: failed to list *v1.Order: request to convert CR from an invalid group/version: acme.cert-manager.io/v1alpha2 E0604 15:54:22.052241       1 reflector.go:148] k8s.io/client-go@v0.27.1/tools/cache/reflector.go:231: Failed to watch *v1.Order: failed to list *v1.Order: request to convert CR from an invalid group/version: acme.cert-manager.io/v1alpha2`